# git: send unmodified file in a commit and in a pull request

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'am working on a branch named dev but when I do my commit I found files which I didn't modified. can any one tell me what is the problem or gives me some advices where can I search a solution for my problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please try to clarify your question.

Comment: for example I did a fork for a projects and then I cloned it to my local machine. When I try to create a new branch, some files is added even if I didn't change anything in those files. Also when I try to do a pull request I find those files (which I didn't modify) and as comment  I found : Binary file modified.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing the following after you have cloned the repo?

- **git fetch origin**
- **git reset --hard origin/master**
- checkout to a new branch **git checkout -b dev**
- change files if required.
- **git add** the changes files.
- **git commit**
- **git push  dev**